# How do I export my code into an app file? (iPhone)

Tags: iphone

I followed some simple "make your first iPhone app" guide.
I tried it in a emulator, and it worked fine, but how can I create the .app (or whatever the extension is) file?

Answer (score 2):

You can either build it for distribution, or archive it, open the Organizer, and share it with the .ipa extension. I don't think .app is possible.

Comment: I'm not very good with macs or using xcode.
How would I go about doing that?

Comment: @tim it's in the window menu I believe.  And you can get the .app file out of the .ipa, it's a .zip :)  you can't share it (or put it on your own phone) unless you are a registered developer (payed the $99 per year so you can put apps on the store)

Comment: Yes, you must be a registered developer. To see about the second option, go to testflightapp.com and follow the instructions for archiving your app. Option 1 is only for submitting your app to the App Store.

Comment: Jack, how do I even get an ipa file?
:S

Comment: Choose "Build and Archive", go to the Organiser, find the app you just built, and click Share.

Comment: I see no "Build and Archive" option?

Comment: A website said Product -> Archive first.
The option 'Archive' is there, but I can not click it.
What gives? ;S

Comment: Listen, I really don't know what you are going to use a .app file for, if that even exists. But due to the way Apple handles certificates, you can't just export a .app file and expect it to run on an iOS device. If you want people to test your app, use testflightapp.com, if you want to put it on the App Store, follow Apple's instructions.

Comment: I just want peoplt to test it.
I'm trying to get a IPA file, a website said I should first go Products -> Archive
But thr Archive option is unavailible for me.
It's there, not not clickable.

Comment: Make sure iOS Device is selected.

Comment: My iPhone is connected, it shows up in iTunes,
but if I choose iOS Device it will say there's no iPhone connected...
I thought if might of been becuase my iOS was 4.2 so I upgraded to the 4.3.5, still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode will automatically make the app for you.  Look under products

Comment: Products?
Where's that?

I did a search and saw a .app for a second, but I don't think that was the right one, and I can't find it again anyway...

Comment: If you successfully build your project for "iOS device", you may find a "Product" group in XCode's file explorer. Under that group, you may find a ProductName.app file. That is what your are looking for. Right click on that file, check "Show in finder", then you can locate that file in finder. You can send that file(actually more like a folder) to your tester, they can install from iTunes.